# Ignore trials in a repeated measures design?

Tags: lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, multilevel-analysis

I am planning to run an analysis on data where each participant rated (scale 1 to 7) two types of products - three products of type A and three products of type B. I am only interested to know whether on an average, ratings for type A and B differed. I am not interested in product level stats.

To illustrate, the data follows this structure:

id, type, product, rating||
1,A,1,4||
1,A,2,5||
1,A,3,3||
1,B,1,3||
1,B,2,4||
1,B,3,5||
2,A,1,3||
2,A,2,2||

I only want to know whether type A and B differ. Can I run the following code?

```r
model <- lmer(rating ~ type + (1|id), data = mydata)
```

I can also add two fixed effects for 'product' above, if needed. However, question is that although 'product' is nested within 'type', is it incorrect for me to ignore this nesting?